Access VBA Update Error 3073 when Executing
I am using Access and am trying to update an sql table Stock using a form.I have create a Button and typed the code below:
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE dbo_Stock " & _
                  " SET StockLink =" & Me.idtxt & _
                  ", Code ='" & Me.codetxt & "'" & _
                  ", Details ='" & Me.dettxt & "'" & _
                  " WHERE StockLink= ' & Me.idtxt.'"

However I keep getting the Error 3073 on the Line   " WHERE StockLink= ' & Me.idtxt.'"

What is the error message? Try " WHERE StockLink= '" & Me.idtxt. & "'"

Operation must use an updatable query. (Error 3073)

You included '& Me.idtxt.' as part of the string. You need to append the idtxt value to the string between the single quote characters. You have good examples in the previous 2 lines.
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE dbo_Stock " & _
                  " SET StockLink =" & Me.idtxt & _
                  ", Code ='" & Me.codetxt & "'" & _
                  ", Details ='" & Me.dettxt & "'" & _
                  " WHERE StockLink= '" & Me.idtxt & "'"

I also corrected the idtxt control name. You can't use a space, period (.), exclamation mark (!), or the characters @, &, $, # in the name.

Consider using a saved query to avoid messy VBA quotation and concatenation. Saved queries can reference form controls.
SQL
UPDATE dbo_Stock
SET 
  StockLink = Forms!myForm!idtxt,
  Code = Forms!myForm!codetxt, 
  Details = Forms!myForm!dettxt 
WHERE StockLink= Forms!myForm!idtxt

VBA
CurrentDb.Execute "mySavedQuery"

